# Android: How to move a file to another folder using SAF(storage access framework), and how to list file with display name?

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

As Google is trying to enforcing apps to use SAF for storage access, I am trying to adapt my app to use SAF replacing java file io apis.

I have spent many hours study the SAF APIs (mainly DocumentFile and DocumentContract classes) but still have some difficulties.

First one is how to move a file to another directory? DocumentFile does have a method to rename a file, but it is just the display name of the file. How can I move a file to another folder, if it is a huge file which I don't want to copy it. Assume src and dst are on the same partition.

Second question is how to list child files efficiently. I checked the [source code](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_support/blob/androidx-master-dev/documentfile/src/main/java/androidx/documentfile/provider/TreeDocumentFile.java) and found that DocumentFile.listFiles() impl only queries the child files with single projection [ID]. And later when I want to display the files in a list view with their names, the call to DocumentFile.getName() will trigger another query via content resolver for each file again. This is a huge impact on the performance of the code. Especially when I try to sort an array of DocumentFile by their names, 30+ files will cost 600+ms, which is far beyond the acceptable. I doubt whether I am using the correct API set. Could anyone point out a better way to list files with names (and other properties)?

Comment: Use DocumentsContract to list files and directories. Query the content resolver with the obtained uri. It's 20 times faster.

Comment: @blackapps DocumentsContract.moveDocument is available from API 24. Is there a way to support API 21?

Comment: Dont think so. Never used moveDocument. Experimenting now. How do you determine the value for the second parameter (the parent dir) if you have only an uri for the source file?

Comment: To answer my own question, you can't. And if you could you would not have read or write rights for that parent directory to move a file from it. (Assuming that you only once picked a source file and a destination directory). Just my thougths.

Comment: DocumentsContract.moveDocument() can move a file or a directory i now tested. Both. But.. on the same partition.

Comment: To support API 21: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-document

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47366768/how-to-list-all-files-inside-a-directory-including-sub-directories-efficiently

Answer (score 2):

[Simple Storage](https://github.com/anggrayudi/SimpleStorage) is a library that simplify SAF across API levels. Suppose that you want to move a MP4 file from directory `Video` in external storage into directory `Others` in SD card. Let's assume that `AAAA-BBBB` as SD card's storage ID:

```kotlin
val source = DocumentFileCompat.fromSimplePath(context, basePath = "Video/Infinity War.mp4")
val targetFolder = DocumentFileCompat.fromSimplePath(context, storageId = "AAAA-BBBB", basePath = "Others")

// To move file:
source.moveFileTo(context, targetFolder, callback)

// To copy file:
source.copyFileTo(context, targetFolder, callback)
```