# How to read file content using document id

Tags: android

I'm requesting a directory tree from a user and I want to read all files. I'm then using something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41096332/issues-traversing-through-directory-hierarchy-with-android-storage-access-framew) to traverse all the files. I want to then read the files (specifically create InputStreams). I tried to find a way to use COLUMN_DOCUMENT_ID and the various open file methods but they either require Uri or filepath and I can't find a way to get one from the document id. I found [this method](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/provider/DocumentsProvider.html#openDocument(kotlin.String,%20kotlin.String,%20android.os.CancellationSignal)) which seems like it would work for me, but it's on an abstract class and I couldn't find an implementation for the android file system. Is there a standard way to do this? I'm probably missing something obvious.

Comment: From your linked-to question, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49300404/115145) would seem to be what you are looking for. Given that `Uri`, use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content.

Comment: Doesn't this create uri pointing to all children? How would I go about opening each of them? As I understand it I couldn't pass a file id there, because it requires the id to be a directory id.

Comment: Oh, sorry, you're right. I was not paying close enough attention. [`buildDocumentUri()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsContract.html#buildDocumentUri(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) is the method that you want, AFAIK.

Comment: In the code for the listing you see                  final Uri newNode = DocumentsContract.buildChildDocumentsUriUsingTree(rootUri, docId); . You can use that uri to tet the content resolver open an input stream.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this and worked out the following way of doing it.

[buildDocumentUriUsingTree()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsContract#buildDocumentUriUsingTree(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String)) does this.

When the user chooses a directory, with SAF storage picker, the URI for that directory is returned in **onActivityResult**. You will need to take persistable permission on that URI, like this:

```
getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(theSafReturnedTreeUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
```

You can store the String returned by **theSafReturnedTreeUri.toString()** in order to reconstruct that **URI** anytime using:

```
Uri.parse(Uri.decode(theString));
```

When you want to access a file under that directory, use **buildDocumentUriUsingTree**, passing it theSafReturnedTreeUri and the Document ID returned when using ContentResolver to query for COLUMN_DOCUMENT_ID.

```
Uri myFileUri = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUriUsingTree(theSafReturnedTreeUri, theDocIdQueriedForWithContentResolver);
```

That gives you a working URI for the file that you should be able to use with [ContentResolver.openInputStream](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver#openInputStream(android.net.Uri)).