# Get all DocumentFile included the ones contained in sub folders efficiently with Storage Access Framework

Tags: android, android-10.0, storage-access-framework, android-11

If I try to get all `DocumentFile` with `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()` it returns me only `DocumentFiles` on the first level of the `Uri` without the ones in the subfolders.

If in order to get also all `DocumentFile` in sub folders, I try to check what `DocumentFile` is a directory, recursively passing its `Uri` in the method that uses `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()`, the whole procedure is **extremely slow**.

Is there a better way to do this (without methods that use classic storage access)?

**EDIT**

The approach above, actually it's not simply slow, but totally stuck. 
This due to the fact the `DocumentFile` objects of folders return always the root file list rather than their content list as supposed due to a weird SAF behavior explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62375696/unexpected-behavior-when-documentfile-fromtreeuri-is-called-on-uri-of-subdirec) and this caused a loop.

Comment: I suspect that there is no good way to avoid that. If there is, it would [involve using `DocumentsContract` more directly](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/11/23/scoped-storage-stories-documentscontract.html). `DocumentFile` is a convenience wrapper around queries and other calls made to `DocumentsContract` via a `ContentResolver`.

Comment: Yes DocumenFile is slow. Still i advise to use it first as it is not that difficult. Then after a while when one sits down to take a rest and complains about slowness we advice to use DocumentsContract. It is up to twenty times as fast as DocumentFile. And about as fast as when using the File class.

Comment: In what way can I achieve what described above with `DocumentsContract`?

Comment: @blackapps I have tried and actually this SAF seems much more messed than what I could have initially imagined. Is this a good implementation?  :/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62375696/unexpected-behavior-when-documentfile-fromtreeuri-is-called-on-uri-of-subdirec

Comment: Yes i saw you were inspired by the f word ;-). But No, as it uses DocumentFile.

Comment: Look at the code for void traverseDirectoryEntries(Uri rootUri) in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41096332/issues-traversing-through-directory-hierarchy-with-android-storage-access-framew It gets you started with listing fast.

Comment: `due to the fact the DocumentFile objects of folders return always the root file list `. No. Then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @blackapps With that code the problem remains, I have already tried it, and not even with any of the edit suggested in answers works. (And btw in `listFiles()`is called `buildChildDocumentsUri` too, but any DocumentFile created with child Uri returns me always data of the dad, and if I try to format the Uri manually as a non-Child to try to avoid this weird behavior it returns me a security exception).  If I'm doing something wrong show me how create  `DocumentFile` from subfolders that list their subcontent programmatically, it should be a very easy task if really SAF is good as you say.

Comment: Show your recursive function using DocumentFile. Show your recursive function using DocumentsContract. (In your post, not in comments). Show how you call it/them from onActivityResult().

Comment: @blackapps I don't' think would be useful. I have already shown here the details about the real culprit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62375696/unexpected-behavior-when-documentfile-fromtreeuri-is-called-on-uri-of-subdirec  If you want to avoid too wording in comment, would be enough to show just a working snippet to generate a `DocumentFile` related to a subfolder starting from  the `DocumentFile` related to its parent  folder in the answer section(if possible), I will accept and upvote the answer, that certainly will be useful to whole community, and everybody will be happy.

Comment: That is not how it goes here. You post your code. You tell the troubles. Then we correct.

Comment: @blackapps I have posted the codeline used in the other related question and even the `Uri` returned. Posting a bunch of code that has nothing to do with the problem of the question itself since it's clear the culprit of error and where it happens, it's not needed and makes the question unnecessarily long. (Note I'm member of Stackoverflow since 8 years, I know how it goes here.)

Comment: I am having the same exact issue. Did you ever figure it out?