# Unexpected behavior when DocumentFile.fromTreeUri() is called on Uri of subdirectory DocumentFile object

Tags: android, android-10.0, storage-access-framework, android-11

If I call  `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()` on main directory and I list its content, it returns all `DocumentFile` object related to folders and files contained in the directory as expected, but when I try to call `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()` on the `Uri` of one of the `DocumentFile` folders inside it, rather than returning all `DocumentFile` objects related to folders and files contained in the subdirectory as expected, it actually returns exactly the same content of the call on its root `Uri`

E.g. 
I have a Download folder with 3 files and a subfolder with 2 files contained in it structured in this way

```
Download
-->file1
-->file2
-->file3
-->Subfolder
----->subfile1
----->subfile2
```

If I call  `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri().listFiles()` on the Download folder `Uri` picked through intent callback `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ADownload`
It returns me

```
-->file1
-->file2
-->file3
-->Subfolder
```

Till now all it's ok, now if I try to get `Uri` of `DocumentFile` object related to `Subfolder`calling `mysub.getUri()` I get `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ADownload/document/primary%3ADownload%2FSubfolder` that apparently would seem correct, but If I call `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri().listFiles()`on it, when I list its content I get again

```
-->file1
-->file2
-->file3
-->Subfolder
```

Exactly as the call on the main Download folder Uri. The same happens if I call `mysub.listFiles()` directly. 
This seems a totally illogical design.

How could I actually get correctly the `DocumentFile` objects related to Subfolder from `DocumentFile` related to its parent in order that Subfolder `DocumentFile` can list its content rather than content of its parent?

Comment: "calling mysub.getUri()" -- rather than getting the `Uri`, then re-wrapping it in a `DocumentFile`, try calling `listFiles()` on `mysub`.

Comment: @CommonsWare This is an horrible design that can lead to a lot of problems. Is there a way to check if an `Uri` will be treated as current `DocumentFile` `Uri` or as "its dad" `Uri`?

Comment: "This is an horrible design that can lead to a lot of problems" -- I cannot argue with that. "Is there a way to check if an Uri will be treated as current DocumentFile Uri or as "its dad" Uri?" -- I do not know what you mean by that. A tree has two `Uri` values, one for itself (`buildTreeDocumentUri()` on `DocumentsContract`) and one representing the collection of children (`buildChildDocumentsUri()` on `DocumentsContract`). I think `isTreeUri()` on `DocumentsContract` will distinguish between them, though I am not certain.

Comment: @CommonsWare However I have tried to call listFiles on mysub as suggested in your first comment and problem remains exactly the same: even `mysub.listFiles() ` returns files of the root.

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't had a need to try traversing a document tree (going into sub-trees), so I'm just trying to point out known problems. Given [the limitations of `listFiles()`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/12/14/scoped-storage-stories-listfiles-woe.html), you may be better served working with `DocumentsContract` for your tree traversal. Also, you might check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/47366768/115145 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/41096332/115145.

Comment: @CommonsWare `DocumentContract` seems another complicated mess. Not sure how I can migrate all without another hell of issues. Anyway I have seen that `DocumentFile` method `listFiles()` under the hood uses exactly `DocumentContract` method `buildChildDocumentsUriUsingTree`, so likely I will have same issue even with `DocumentContract`. Such method apparently seems meant to give childs, it seems too senseless I actually get the root content. I'm starting to have the doubt there is some serious bug in the SAF itself.

Answer (score 10):

I have the same problem. I solved it after upgrading the documentfile version.

`implementation 'androidx.documentfile:documentfile:1.0.1'`

Comment: This works! But why is this "new" DocumentFile dependency not being automatically rolled into whatever androidx library it's a part of? This bug was fixed in February 2019 so what gives?  https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/documentfile#1.0.1

Comment: Thanks for this. In my case it was androix.appcompat 1.4.1 that was including the 1.0.0 dependency.